# Is DataFrameReader faster than reading\fetching data by hiveContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is DataFrameReader faster than reading\fetching data by hiveContext e.g. (hiveContext.sql("select a,b,c from table) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `hiveContext` will use a `DataFrameReader` underneath it in order to fulfill the above request. Its faster to use the Hive SQL since its been optimized.

Comment: OK, Thanks....but what if by using DataFrameReader we directly read partitioned folder ...instead of using filters in hive SQL,,,,,will that be faster ?

Comment: @sahebbhattu Im now confused, are you saying that you've got data pre-partitioned already and its in the format that you'd like post filtering?

Comment: Yes, I am fetching hive external tables and those are partitioned. So I m  thinking to fetch it directly from DataFrameReader

Comment: then its the same speed since Hive would do the same thing.

Comment: @sahebbhattu If you've found this answer helpful, you can always mark it as best answer.